# How to change hyphenation language without Babel?

Tags: hyphenation, babel

I would like to change hyphenation pattern in `pdlatex` without using `babel`, because `babel` **kills** my document class in my language (hungarian). Unfortunately I cannot find a way to change the pattern even using the hint in `hyph-utf8` package:

```
\language=\l@hu
```

but this one says that 'Missing number, treated as zero'. The other one does not work either:

```
\hyphenrules{langname}
```

and tells me the 'Missing number...' message again (I think the latter macro uses `\l@hu`).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [Similar question for LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678184/26287)

Answer (score 3):

The symbolic name for the language is `\l@hungarian`; but to be certain you need to look at the file `language.dat` that has, on a typical TeX Live distribution, the path

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/tex/generic/config/language.dat
```

although the one which is really used is

```
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat
```

(usually, if there are no site specific changes, they are identical). The relevant line are

```
% from hyphen-hungarian:
hungarian loadhyph-hu.tex
```

that tell LaTeX to define a `\l@hungarian` set of hyphenation patterns by looking at the file `loadhyph-hu.tex`.

There are a couple of ways to cope with the problem:

```
\RequirePackage[english=hungarian]{hyphsubst}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
```

This, however, will make it impossible to use English in the document (with correct hyphenation patterns). You can also do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\hyphenrules{hungarian}
```

and, for the possible parts in English, use the `otherlanguage` environment.

In both cases you'll have to redefine the fixed tags, which you easily find in the `hungarian.ldf` file.

Comment: @Gergely This should work the same. Just check how the language is called; it should be `hungarian` as well.

Comment: Actually I use MiKTeX at the moment, and MiKTeX has the `language.dat` file under `generic/babel` but it does not mention hungarian language. Nevertheless I tried `\language=\l@hungarian` and it has solved the problem stated. The only thing I do not understand where the `hungarian` name comes from?