# Possible to load only hyphenation in LuaLaTeX, without babel or polyglossia?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

Using only lualatex, recent (post-2020) version. Always utf-8, always OpenType fonts. Language will be one of the major Western European, possibly Latin-alphabet Eastern European, never anything else. Above all: No math! No Tikz! No tables! No bibtex! Just ordinary literary typing.

Question: Is it possible to load and use language-specific hyphenation, but without also loading either babel or polyglossia? If so, what is needed? Documents will be monolingual.

Reason I ask: Both babel and polyglossia have a wonderful collection of options and commands. These packages not only load the hyphenation, they make typographic adjustments. I wish to limit the available adjustments to a small number (such as French spacing, style of quotation marks) which I will code by other means. My user base writes literature, no math, not professional articles. Some of the numerous macro command sequences get in the way.

Comment: you can load babel with the base option, see the documentation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I will have a look. But you have identified part of the reason for my question. Babel does not mention its package options until page 15 of the docs. At least it is shown in the menu. The list of supported languages is not until page 22, and I do not see a menu item. I cannot ask users to shuffle through large docs for numerous packages that contain information that is not relevant to the usage.

Comment: why should your user have to look into the babel documentation? I thought you want to provide suitable templates -- and as a developer you have to read documentation.

Comment: Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/luahyphenrules.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer 1. Babel package options are in section 1.11. There is no `base` option listed there. It is described in section 1.12. I believe the babel docs should list the `base` option, with `see section 1.12 for details`. 2. Apparently, the `silent` option is incompatible with the `base` option. Not obvious why. 3. As with many packages, `babel` has piles of info for OT1 encoding, other engines, and many other things that make reading the docs difficult. 4. Remember the infamous `goto` command for certain computer languages? Like that!

Comment: @JavierBezos Will have a look. When I searched for things involving `hyphen...` it did not occur to me to look for `luahyphen...`.

Comment: @JavierBezos That is EXACTLY what I need. Tested it, works. Please put your comment as an answer. I believe others need to know this, not just myself. Note: My own attempt to manually load hyphenation rules failed, presumably due to catcodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a short package for this purpose, `luahyphenrules`. It reads `language.dat` as `babel` does, and nothing more. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luahyphenrules}

\begin{document}

\HyphenRules{spanish}

\showhyphens{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

\HyphenRules{english}

\showhyphens{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}

\end{document}
```

The log shows:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--9
[] \TU/lmr/m/n/10 su-per-ca-li-fra-gi-lis-ti-cex-pia-li-do-cious

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 13--13
[] \TU/lmr/m/n/10 su-per-cal-ifrag-ilis-tic-ex-pi-ali-do-cious
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'd recommend it but you can just input the patterns

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlanguage\frfr
\language=\frfr
\input{loadhyph-fr}
\language=0

\begin{document}


\typeout{EN}
\showhyphens{quelques mots pas en anglais pour tester la césure}

\typeout{FR}
\language\frfr
\showhyphens{quelques mots pas en anglais pour tester la césure}

\end{document}
```

makes a log

```
EN

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 12--12
[] \TU/lmr/m/n/10 quelques mots pas en anglais pour tester la cé-sure
FR

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--16
[] \TU/lmr/m/n/10 quelques mots pas en an-glais pour tes-ter la cé-sure
```

showing the changed hyphenation.

Comment: That's OK, but the `luahyphenrules` is even better, for those of us who use lualatex.

Comment: @rallg comes to same thing  I think. Personally I'd use babel, you said you wanted to do it directly without the package layer, so I show that and you respond that you prefer a package interface:-)

Comment: @rallg my answer is luatex only, you can't load patterns in to pdflatex.

Comment: Thanks. I will play with this some more. But I must say, I admire the one-page documentation for `luahyphenrules`, which also mentions where I can find the acceptable language names.

Comment: @rallg the usable names for this version woud be the filenames in `/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/hyph-utf8/loadhyph/` or equivalent. (but as I say I wouldn't use the form I show here I'd use Javier's  code from babel or perhaps luahyphenrules  so if I don't get the tick I'll survive:-)

Comment: The `loadhyph` directory contains whatever has already been loaded via `tlmgr` or whatever. Good info for determining whether the user needs to load more `hyphen-Z` packages. The `*.dat` file mentioned by `luahyphenrules` also mentions possible languages, not just those already loaded. For those (such as myself) who have a TeX system with a low numer of packages, this is an important difference.